# How do I write this block of code in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to use linq as many times as possible and I have no idea how to use linq in this type of method.

I've tried some code from certain webs however none of them worked

```
List<MemorableD> memorables = new List<MemorableD>();
    List<StateMD> states = new List<StateMD>();
    void Find(List<MemorableD> selected)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < states.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < memorables.Count; j++)
            {
                if (states[i].Month == memorables[j].Month && states[i].Day == memorables[j].Day)
                {
                    MemorableD select = new MemorableD(memorables[j].Year, memorables[j].Month, memorables[j].Day, memorables[j].Event, states[i].Event);
                    selected.Add(select);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to write this add method with LINQ

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Perhaps there's something in particular you're stuck on?

Comment: `I need to use linq as many times as possible` can you tell us why for this requirement perhaps?

Comment: Im learning linq and I have been told that you can use linq for almost everything.

Comment: "Can" and "Need" are pretty different.

Comment: True, but that doesn't necessarily make anything cleaner, easier and or  maintainable at all times either... `I have no idea how to use linq on this type`, there's no such thing as `linq on this type`. If it's not a requirement, then do it as you see fit and works, otherwise show us what you have *tried* and we would be glad to explain in detail and help you out. TBH as your question is stated you are asking us *to do it* as you haven't shown your approach, this isn't how SO works.

Comment: Could you share your attempted code ? It doesn't matter how close you are to the solution or how far you are from it. What matters would be your effort

Comment: Sample data would be helpful too.

Comment: LINQ is handy, but it ends up being a reflection of other aspects of our code. I'd look for every way to make it easier to read without LINQ. That might include `foreach` loops instead of `for` loops and writing a function to compare the month and day of two objects. Maybe using a single `DateTime` property instead of three different properties. If we do all that, then without LINQ it will be easy to read and follow, and LINQ might make it even easier. Also LINQ can end up being like code golf where everything becomes denser and harder to read. It doesn't always help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to break down your problem. If you were to analyse your loops, you are iterating over the States and Memorables, and creating instances of MemorableD where State and Memorable have the same Month and Day and latter adding them to the List.

Translating it to Linq,

```
from StateMD state in states
from MemorableD memorable in memorables
    where state.Month == memorable.Month && state.Day == memorable.Day
let selectValue = new MemorableD(memorable.Year, memorable.Month, memorable.Day, memorable.Event, state.Event)
select selectValue
```

The second part of the problem is to add it to the List called selected. You can add an IEnumerable to selected using the AddRange method.

So, combining the Linq statement with AddRange method,

```
selected.AddRange(from StateMD state in states
                              from MemorableD memorable in memorables
                              where state.Month == memorable.Month && state.Day == memorable.Day
                              let selectValue = new MemorableD(memorable.Year, memorable.Month, memorable.Day, memorable.Event, state.Event)
                              select selectValue);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to analyze this code more in order to in order to figure out how linq works !